Combined SR and GR effects for time dilation in uniform gravitational field
I was reading David Morin's "Classical Mechanics" Chapter 14 and he claims that the combined effect of time dilation on a body moving at speed $v$ is $$d\tau=(1+gx)\sqrt{1-v^2}dt$$ ($c=1$). In an exercise at the end of the chapter he tries to justify this claim by asking you to derive the time elapsed on a distant planet $dt_p$ measured by a uniformly accelerating observer as a function of the time elapsed in the istantaneous inertial frame of reference of the accelerating observer $dt$. So I have two questions really:

Is it the same thing to calculate the proper time $d\tau$ and the above-defined $dt_p$? In other words is calculating the proper time on the accelerating frame for an inertial observer the same as doing the calculation the other way around?

Is the first expression correct and if so, why is it not true that $d\tau \gamma=dt$? My claim is that it has something to do with the metric but I don't know a lot more.



You can simply calculate the Lorentz factor in the Schwarzschild metric and use that as well. No equivalence-principle reasoning required.

Ok so I don't have to take into account different effects but it is all enconded in the metric ? I guess the result the books claims is a first order approximation

Yes, the metric encodes all the time dilation effects. It was a fun day for me when I realized that you can derive all of SR from the Minkowski metric.

@controlgroup agreed 100%, this need to be hammered home at every opportunity.  Unfortunately there are too many people here who like to prattle on about simultaneity, as if that means anything physical or useful to the typical OP.  I believe these folk can no longer relate to a time before they understood it themselves.
